# Error stating "The method 'orderBy' isn't defined for the type 'Future'."

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

```
class CrudMethods {
  Future<void> addData(blogData) async {
    print(blogData);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("blogs")
        .add(blogData)
        .orderBy("ts", descending: true)
        .then((value) => print(value))
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

The error is with "orderBy("ts", descending: true)"

The error states:

> The method 'orderBy' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please share error text properly

Comment: you can't use `orderby` when adding, only when retrieving

Comment: The error message is correct and (as Peter explained) makes sense to me. What do you expect this code to do? In other words: if you remove the `.orderBy("ts", descending: true)` (which will remove the error message), what's wrong with the result you get?